# Array modifier changing second array modifier

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, modifiers

I'm trying to array an object in two directions, like this:

[image]

But when I try to have both at the same time, the first array influences the other and the objects will not touch anymore:

[image]

So how can I make both modifiers independent of each other?

Comment: Hum... A question about Modifiers that doesn't show the modifier stack

Comment: Use Object offset in Array settings. Pick different objects (empties) for different offsets. Modifiers won't be independant on each other on one object

Answer (score 1):

It would be helpful if you included your modifier-settings in the screenshot. It is difficult to locate the error without that information.

Anyway I created a setup like you want with two array modifiers. 
You can see the settings in this screenshot.

[image: Screenshot two array modifiers]